# How should you deploy a combination of serverless and non-serverless resources in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I need to deploy a combination of serverless (API GW and Lambda) and non serverless resources (RDS, ElastiCache etc). With a SAM template it's easy to deploy all these resources. But should I put them all in one template or should I use a serverless template for example API GW and Lambda and a CloudFormation template for different static resources? Is there some AWS best practice?

Answer (score 2):

AWS SAM templates are a superset of CloudFormation and therefore, in addition to its inbuilt shortcuts for Serverless resources, also supports defining any resources that CloudFormation supports; using AWS SAM you can not only define Serverless resources and applications but also any other resources supported by CloudFormation. Although there is no best practice for which templating standard to use for which resource(s), per-se, you may wish to consider that adopting a single templating standard for all your Infrastructure as Code templates may make learning and adopting that standard easier than adopting multiple standards at the same time.

Regarding organization of resources, one strategy you can use to organize and/or isolate resources is CloudFormations `Nested Stacks` concept, which SAM has extended to `Nested Applications`. Using a “nested” approach you can separate out and organize resources in to individual templates, or `stacks`, that make logical sense for your use case, and deploy them all using the `root stack`. This approach has many advantages, including that it allows you to reuse your `stacks` in other nested applications.

You can learn more about `CloudFormation Nested Stacks` [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html) and `AWS SAM Nested Applications` [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-template-nested-applications.html), and the AWS SAM Nested Stack [announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-nested-applications-for-aws-sam-and-the-aws-serverless-application-repository/) has a great tutorial you can follow to familiarize yourself with nested applications quickly.

Comment: To add to this, think about what you want to version and release into production. If you version and release everything together, one stack with nested stacks makes sense. If you've got 2 services that you version and release independently, two separate stacks makes sense.